# rand() return the same number

Tags: c, random, srand

I am making a simple example in C with rand() but the function always return the same number despite i am using srand().

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int generate(int min, int max)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        printf("Number random %d = %d\n", i, generate(1, 100));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution :

> Number random 0 = 40 Number random 1 = 40 Number random 2 = 40 Number
>   random 3 = 40 Number random 4 = 40 Number random 5 = 40 Number random
>   6 = 40 Number random 7 = 40 Number random 8 = 40 Number random 9 = 40

Comment: You shouldn't force a new seed every use. You should use ``srand`` at application start, not every time. BTW, you should really consider using ``<random>`` instead of old-school ``rand``.

Comment: try init the random numbers one time at the beginning of your main function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are reseeding it every time, and as your program probably runs very quickly, your seed value (time()) is the same for each call as it's smallest increment is 1 second.

Try moving `srand()` into `main()` instead and call it once

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly calling `srand` ruins the statistical properties of the generator.

Call it no more than once.

(The observed behaviour is caused by `time(NULL)` returning the same value in every iteration of the loop.)